# Cannot get data in a view after parsing json data from controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, linq, visual-studio

I want to display data in a viw after parsing json data from controller and also save it in database through linq query, I have created model, view and controller but can't get the data in a view, and it is not saved in database, i have take a list of type EmployeeModel and if id matches added record to that list and then want to store that record in database and send it to view. I am getting error in view that foreach does not implement ienumerator. Please help to sort out this problem thanks......

```
namespace jsonMvcApplication.Models
{
public class jsonData
{
    public List<rootelem> data { get; set; }
}

public class rootelem
{
    public List<employeeObj> employee { get; set; }
}

public class employeeObj
{
    public List<DataElement> empdetails { get; set; }
}

public class DataElement
{
    public ulong empid { get; set; }
    public string empname { get; set; }
    public string empdept { get; set; }
    public List<empphone> empphone { get; set; }
}

public class empphone
{
    public string home { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
}
}
```

-Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var empid=111;
    WebClient c = new WebClient();
    EmployeeModel empClass;
    var Emplist=new List<EmployeeModel>();

    var jsonstring = @"{""data"":[{""employee"":[{""empdetails"":[{""empid"":""98977"",""empname"":""John"",""empdept"":""HR"",""empphone"":[{""home"":""868685768"",""mobile"":""89886654""}] }] }] }] }";

    empClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonData>(jsonstring);

    foreach (var items in empClass.data[0].employee[0].empdetails)
    {
    if (empid==111) 
       {
        Emplist.Add(empClass);
       }
    }
          return view(Emplist);
}
```

- View

```
@model jsonMvcApplication.Models.DataElement

<table>
@foreach(var empdetails in Model)
{
<tr> <td> @empdetails.empid </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> @empdetails.empname </td> </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: How about posting a *compilable* code? What is `myData`?  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<empClass>(jsonstring);`  is not correct. `empClass` is not a **Type**

Answer (score 0):

your model definition

```
@model jsonMvcApplication.Models.DataElement
```

seems to not match with what you return in your controller right?
Emplist <> DataElement

Answer (score 0):

Try below in your view

```
<script>
var values = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Values));
</script>
```