# MVC View - JSON not parsing correctly from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I am unable to understand why my JSON is not parsing correctly.  I am parsing a c# dictionary to a JSON string in my controller. The output is correct there.  When I pass the string back to my partial view, it does not render properly, and I am getting "Unexpected Token &" Ive tried it multilple ways in returning it to the view, but to no avail.

**View:**

```
    var data = @Model.JSONDict
    //data output - var data = {&quot;3/1/2014&quot;:2,&quot;2/28/2014&quot;:1,&quot;2/27/2014&quot;:1,&quot;2/26/2014&quot;:0,&quot;2/25/2014&quot;:0,&quot;2/24/2014&quot;:0,&quot;2/23/2014&quot;:0}


    //var keys = Object.keys(data);
```

**Controller:**

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);

//Resulting Output = "{\"3/1/2014\":2,\"2/28/2014\":1,\"2/27/2014\":1,\"2/26/2014\":0,\"2/25/2014\":0,\"2/24/2014\":0,\"2/23/2014\":0}"

            ViewData["allEntries"] = output;
            model.JSONDict = output;

            return PartialView("_Graph", model);
```

I have also tried parsing out the & acocording to this post: [Cannot get data in a view after parsing json data from controller in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010622/cannot-get-data-in-a-view-after-parsing-json-data-from-controller-in-asp-net-mvc) like so, but getting the same error message:

```
storejson= getJSonObject("@ViewBag.JsonData");

function getJSonObject(value) {
    return $.parseJSON(value.replace(/&quot;/ig, '"'));
}
```

Comment: In your view try `var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.JSONDict))`

Comment: Ok, I post an answer then. If it works and if you want you may accept it. Happy coding :)

Comment: as the answer works for you (@aoakeson), please `accept` it as answer as it'll be helpful for others also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the output the JSON is encoded. In order to deal with this you can use the `@Html.Raw()` like so :

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.JSONDict))
```

But be advised that using `@Html.Raw()` may cause some security issues so it must be used with caution.